# The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, shared-libraries

Hello I am working on a Xamarin cross platform application using PCL for code sharing, and when I try to build the solution, I have the following error message:

> Error CS0012  The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I am targeting version 4.5 of the .NET framework. This error occured when I build, on a file generated in the obj folder.

I tried changing the references of the project but the only reference is "NET" (version 4.0.0) and I can't delete it nor add any other system reference so I don't know what to do.

Comment: You can't target .Net Framework 4.5 on Xamarin, that uses Mono.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, tried changing targeted framework to 4.0 but I keep getting the same error. Any idea ?

Comment: You can target the full .net framework in a mobile app.  why do you need to?

Comment: I am new to Xamarin, what I want to do is use Xamarin.Forms and PCL in order to share my code. I tried targeting 4.0 but it is not compatible with Xamarin Forms. So I try targeting 4.5, but I have the reported error.

Comment: how did you create the app?   What version of visual studio are you using?